# Error 'cannot find name ...' using karma-typescript-preprocessor plugin

Tags: gruntjs, typescript, karma-runner

I am trying to automate unit test execution using grunt karma and karma-typescript-preprocessor.

However, when I run 'grunt watch', karma outputs the following error :
ERROR [preprocessor.typescript]: /home/loic/Code/appName/src/app/app.spec.ts.ktp.ts(15,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'expect'.

This error happens with a lot of names : 'describe, angular, expect 'etc

The strange thing is that when i run the command line 'tsc /path/to/app.spec.ts', the new js file is created, there is no error.

below my karma.conf.js :

```
module.exports = function ( karma ) {
    karma.set({
    /**
     * From where to look for files, starting with the location of this file.
     */
    basePath: '../',

    typescriptPreprocessor: {
        // options passed to the typescript compiler
        options: {
            sourceMap: false, // (optional) Generates corresponding .map file.
            target: 'ES5', // (optional) Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), or 'ES5'
            module: 'amd', // (optional) Specify module code generation: 'commonjs' or 'amd'
            noImplicitAny: false, // (optional) Warn on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type.
            noResolve: true, // (optional) Skip resolution and preprocessing.
            removeComments: true // (optional) Do not emit comments to output.
        },
        // transforming the filenames
        transformPath: function(path) {
            return path.replace(/\.ts$/, '.js');
        }
    },

    /**
     * This is the list of file patterns to load into the browser during testing.
     */
    files: [
    <% scripts.forEach( function ( file ) { %>'<%= file %>',
        <% }); %>
'src/**/*.ts'
],
exclude: [
    'src/assets/**/*.ts',
    'src/typeScript/**/*.ts'
],
    frameworks: [ 'jasmine' ],
    plugins: [ 'karma-jasmine', 'karma-firefox-launcher', 'karma-typescript-preprocessor' ],
    preprocessors: {
    '**/*.ts': 'typescript'
},

/**
 * How to report, by default.
 */
reporters: 'dots',

/**
 * On which port should the browser connect, on which port is the test runner
 * operating, and what is the URL path for the browser to use.
 */
    port: 9018,
    runnerPort: 9100,
    urlRoot: '/',

/**
 * Disable file watching by default.
 */
    autoWatch: false,

/**
 * The list of browsers to launch to test on. This includes only "Firefox" by
 * default, but other browser names include:
 * Chrome, ChromeCanary, Firefox, Opera, Safari, PhantomJS
 *
 * Note that you can also use the executable name of the browser, like "chromium"
 * or "firefox", but that these vary based on your operating system.
 *
 * You may also leave this blank and manually navigate your browser to
 * http://localhost:9018/ when you're running tests. The window/tab can be left
 * open and the tests will automatically occur there during the build. This has
 * the aesthetic advantage of not launching a browser every time you save.
 */
    browsers: [
    'Firefox'
]
});
};
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the line

```
noResolve: true,
```

from the typescriptPreprocessor configuration. It seems to cause the compiler not to resolve your references properly.

Comment: This one fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I ended up doing  gulp tasks to run in sequence typescript compile and karma test.

Answer (score 0):

Set the 'noResolve' value to false, and add the references

I also comment about this here

https://github.com/sergeyt/karma-typescript-preprocessor/issues/29

Answer (score 0):

What helped me is adding

```
///<reference path="../node_modules/karma-typescript-preprocessor/typings/jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
```

On the beginning of each test file.

When I tried adding

```
typescriptPreprocessor: {
    typings: ['path/to/typings/jasmine.d.ts']
...
```

I was getting errors complaining about duplicate definitions...